# Hosting Asp .Net MVC3 Web Application in IIS 7.5

Tags: deployment, iis-7.5, web-deployment, web-hosting

We have developed an application using Asp .Net MVC3 for our Organization.we want to host that Application to Access the Same using a Link from other systems.I did publish the web Application by right clicking on its properties and used web deploy option.Now i can see that Application in IIS under Default website and when i give browse i can view the Application running Properly.but when i try to access the same from another computer using the same link with my system's Ip Address i couldn't Access the Same.It would be great if we get any assistence on this issue.we r struggling on this for past 2 days

Comment: is the other system part of you LAN? can u access your system from the other system using remote desktop? if yes.. check the firewall settings of your system

Comment: Partial views are not loading when hosting the solution on server.is there any way to call controller action method from view without using ajax or jquery?